# How to save tuple become an image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing, tuples

Helo, I just learned to use Python. And i have some arrays in tuple bellow.

```
(array([[ 90,  94,   6],
       [126, 108,  24],
       [180, 116,  42],
       [166, 116,  46],
       [ 72,  94,  31]]), array([[101,  96,  14],
       [190, 165,  84],
       [202, 134,  63],
       [170, 115,  50],
       [ 40,  50,   0]]), array([[145, 125,  53],
       [150, 112,  40],
       [148,  73,   6],
       [156,  90,  31],
       [ 25,  11,   1]]), array([[133, 124,  57],
       [165, 142,  75],
       [195, 142,  77],
       [169, 120,  62],
       [ 82,  74,  28]]), array([[ 73, 105,  40],
       [ 56,  77,  10],
       [138, 135,  67],
       [ 97,  95,  34],
       [ 45,  69,  21]]))
```

How can i turn that tuple become an image? Thanks

Comment: Can you add more clarification? e.g. What do you mean by image?

Comment: @jStaff believe the array represents tuples of colors, and the entire size is NXN (25) representing an image.  I'm guessing this is a duplicate though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

x = (array([[ 90,  94,   6],
   [126, 108,  24],
   [180, 116,  42],
   [166, 116,  46],
   [ 72,  94,  31]]), array([[101,  96,  14],
   [190, 165,  84],
   [202, 134,  63],
   [170, 115,  50],
   [ 40,  50,   0]]), array([[145, 125,  53],
   [150, 112,  40],
   [148,  73,   6],
   [156,  90,  31],
   [ 25,  11,   1]]), array([[133, 124,  57],
   [165, 142,  75],
   [195, 142,  77],
   [169, 120,  62],
   [ 82,  74,  28]]), array([[ 73, 105,  40],
   [ 56,  77,  10],
   [138, 135,  67],
   [ 97,  95,  34],
   [ 45,  69,  21]]))

x = np.array(x)
plot.imshow(x)
```

[image: chart]

Or you can go with [OpenCV's imshow](https://pythonexamples.org/python-opencv-imshow/)